# Android: remove deprecation warning for Html.fromHtml

Tags: android, deprecated, deprecation-warning, fromhtml

I would like to remove the deprecation warning for `Html.fromHtml(string)`.

I tried to do like this:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        htmlSpanned = Html.fromHtml(string,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        htmlSpanned = Html.fromHtml(string);
    }
```

but it still gives me a warning during compilation:

> Warning:(18, 31) [deprecation] fromHtml(String) in Html has been
>   deprecated

Comment: is your minSdkVersion is higher or lower then 24 ?

Comment: in my Gradle file I have: minSdkVersion 15, targetSdkVersion 24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the one-parameter `fromHtml()` is deprecated. The `Build` checks ensure that you will not *call* it on older devices, but it does not change the fact that it is deprecated with a `compileSdkVersion` of 24.

You have four choices:

1. Drop your `compileSdkVersion` below 24. This has rippling effects (e.g., you cannot use 24.x.x versions of the support libraries) and is not a great option.
2. Set your `minSdkVersion` to 24 and get rid of the one-parameter `fromHtml()` call. This is impractical in 2016.
3. Live with the strikethrough and Lint complaints.
4. Add the appropriate `@SuppressLint` annotation to the method, to get the IDE to stop complaining. [As Ahlem Jarrar notes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747567/ahlem-jarrar), the simplest way to add this is via the quick-fix.

Answer (score 4):

If your `minSdkVersion` **is 24 or higher**, use the version of `fromHtml()` [that takes some flags as a parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)) . AFAIK, `FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY` would be the flag value to use for compatibility with the older flag-less fromHtml().

If your minSdkVersion is lower than 24, your choices are:

Always use the `fromHtml()` you are, possibly using the quick-fix **(Alt-Enter)** to suppress the Lint warning

Use both versions of `fromHtml()`: the one taking the flags if your app is running on an API Level 24+ device, or the one without the flags on older devices.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution at one point:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textField.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else {
    textField.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText);
}
```

It worked just fine.

Comment: This is the most optimized solution for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. I mean your code looks well, I tried it and it worked for me.

// get our html content

```
String htmlAsString = getString(R.string.html);
Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlAsString);
```

// used by TextView

// set the html content on the TextView

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(htmlAsSpanned);
```

Our you can try it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

Answer (score 0):

Android or Kotlin or Google has created **HtmlCompat** which can be used instead of the method **Html**. Add this dependency implementation *'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'* to the build.gradle file of your app. Make sure you use the latest version of androidx.core:core.

This allows you to use:

```
 HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```

You can convert the HTML.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY into an additional parameter if you want. This gives you more control about it which flag to use.

You can read more about the different flags on the [HTML Class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)